# Picture password Please on windows 8 professional

Tags: windows-8, passwords

I get the following error:

> "Enrolment failure. There was a failure during the enrolment process. Please try again later"

after I create a picture password and

> "An error occurred capturing your PIN. Please try again later".

How can I fix the problem?

This is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Check [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-security/receiving-an-enrollment-failure-error-message-when/085357db-cd8c-4c50-8f10-e1c61da8f5a0).

Comment: Let me guess your picword... cross and circle at the sun?

Comment: Here is an answer: Don't EVER use picture passwords...

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, images with machines joints and curves is not supported in picture password feature but i have an animals  grass picture password and it works now, I got the same error as you have , i refreshed windows 8, installed all the drivers and it worked for me, another solution which worked for me is to restore the system at the point before the updates but of course you will get the error after a week  or so-

Playing with the registry  is another option but that is riddled and i think will mess up things , but for  your info you have to change the default settings to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"AllowDomainPicturePassword"=dword:00000001
"AllowDomainPINLogon"=dword:00000001

There is another solution [explained in a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_Fj-xIURGY) and it worked for many , you can check that out too